# Turn off Google Account Chooser

Tags: google-account

I'm having big problems with Google Account Chooser so I would like to try turning it off.  I see that this url https://www.google.com/accounts/optintoaccountchooser?optout=1 is supposed to let me do that.  But it just redirects to https://www.google.com/settings/account

Any idea how I can disable Google Account Chooser?

Comment: Have you tried signing out of all your accounts first before going to the URI?

Answer (score 2):

You need to go into your browser settings and delete history, cookies, and saved passwords. Then you'll be able to disable the Account Chooser.

Comment: Chiming in because there's no accepted answer here and I want to confirm that this works: signing out of all accounts before I visited https://www.google.com/accounts/optintoaccountchooser?optout=1 allowed me to disable the chooser.

Answer (score 0):

If your browser is Firefox, use addon [Remove Cookie for Google Account Chooser](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/remove-cookie-for-google-ac/) to disable Google account chooser automatically.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be logged out to access the opt in/out settings for the account chooser. Log out of any Google accounts and *then* visit:

https://www.google.com/accounts/optintoaccountchooser?optout=1

and you'll be all set.